# Pass value of checkbox to array whether it is checked or not

Tags: php, html

I need to pass the value and a couple of other values depending on what checkboxes are checked.  I found posted a couple of other times here to rely on html for this and pass a hidden value before the checkbox :

```
<input type="hidden" value="0"  name="B_1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1"  name="B_1" />
<input type="hidden" value="0"  name="B_2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1"  name="B_2" />
<input type="hidden" value="0"  name="B_3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1"  name="B_3" />
```

Then in the php I am making different associations based on these checkboxes :

```
$b = "Buyers";
$bv1 = "Not a web item";
$bv2 = "Need sample";
$bv3 = "Sample not available";

if ($_POST['B_1']) { $b1 = array( $b , $bv1 , $_POST['B_1'] ); } 
if ($_POST['B_2']) { $b2 = array( $b , $bv2 , $_POST['B_2'] ); } 
if ($_POST['B_3']) { $b3 = array( $b , $bv3 , $_POST['B_3'] ); }
```

when I use `print_r` I am only seeing the arrays for those boxes I checked :

```
Array ( [0] => Buyers [1] => Not a web item [2] => 1 )
```

I expect to see all of the arrays returned regardless of state of checkbox.

```
Array ( [0] => Buyers [1] => Not a web item [2] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => Buyers [1] => Need sample [2] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => Buyers [1] => Sample not available [2] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the use of your hidden fields here at all (also, they shouldn't have the same name as other elements, unless the field is an array). If you're not using them, I propose that you change your HTML to:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="B_1"  name="B_1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="B_2"  name="B_2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="B_3"  name="B_3" />
```

You can store whatever value you need in the checkbox element `value` attribute.

If you need all of the arrays, regardless of whether or not the boxes are checked, the `if` should be removed:

```
$b1 = array( $b , $bv1 , $_POST['B_1'] );
$b2 = array( $b , $bv2 , $_POST['B_2'] );
$b3 = array( $b , $bv3 , $_POST['B_3'] );
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarifying.  I am using the hidden because I want the value of 0 to be passed if the checkbox is not checked.  If I dont do this nothing is returned for the `$_POST`  `[2] =>`  I have read a few places that this is the solution but if you have another idea I would love to hear it.

Comment: You can determine whether the checkbox is checked by doing `isset($_POST['B_1'])` (etc), and determine your values/logic based on that

Comment: ok, thanks Chris.  One more, why is it better to do it that way?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to create and check another element when you have what you need right in front of you -- no? :) Moreover, unless I completely misunderstood what you are (were) trying to accomplish, what you have in your post doesn't really make much sense, seeing as the element names are the same (and, as such, overwritten by their latter counterparts) and you aren't dynamically setting their values in any other way

Comment: When you create more than one input element with the same "name" attribute, just think of it as the later one overriding the first one, and the first one is therefore ignored (unless, as others have said, you're passing as an array). While your current solution might work with some browsers, it shouldn't, and it certainly won't work with all of them. So, that's why it's better to manage the checkbox status on the server end rather than attempt to always fill the variable on the client end.